# Getting number of instances of asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net website and i want to get the number of users currently viewing my site. I am aware that there are some third party softwares available, that would give me the list of the users online but i don't want to do that.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved in asp.net? May be if there are any server variables that would keep a track of the website instances that gives the number of users currently visiting the site. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count users which are using your website at the moment you can use the following code in your global.asax file:

```
private int activeUsers = 0; 
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   activeUsers++; 
   Context.Items["activeUsers"] = activeUsers; 
} 
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   Context.Items.Add("activeUsers", activeUsers); 
} 
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   if(activeUsers > 0) 
   activeUsers--; 
} 
protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   activeUsers = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mug4n. This will definitely help me.

But one question, as this would be at Application level, will i still require to use the Session events?

Also, how can i access this number on the home page.

Comment: I think this method will be highly inaccurate and unreliable.

Comment: why do you think it's highly inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

I would use performance counters instead.

Look under 
ASP.NET Application Performance Counters

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

Comment: Thanks Raj. Do you have an example that you can share pls?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161737/what-are-the-best-asp-net-performance-counters-to-monitor

and 

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/monitoringaspnetapplicationperformance.aspx